# How to get substring from char pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, malloc, substring, memcpy

I want to get substring from char pointer, at line 1 is successfully printed ok but if it is line 2 is unsuccessful. But in the cout prints as it is.

Why? And How do I correct it?

```
char* substring(const char* src, int start_index, int end_index){ // src - source
  int length = end_index - start_index;
  char *dest; // destination
  if (length < 0) {
    return NULL;
  } else {
      dest = (char*)malloc(sizeof (char)* (length + 1));
      dest[length] = '\0';
      memcpy(dest, src + start_index, length);
      return dest;
  }
}
int main() {
  //char *p = "phab"; // line 1
  char *p = substring("alphabet",2, 6); // line 2
  cout << p << endl;
  if (p == "phab") cout << "ok\n";
}
```

Comment: are you mixing C and C++?

Comment: The last line is not good, you compare two adresses. If you want to compare the strings, use strcmp( )

Comment: @SouravGhosh: You cannot mix C and C++ in the same source code. This is C++, not C.

Comment: where I got missed?

Comment: A pointer is not a string, so it has no "substring". If you want strings, use the string class.

Comment: @Olaf Yes, sire, I meant the syntaxes and concepts. Following your comment, using `malloc()` in C++ is almost always a bad idea. :) _I am willing to overlook the tag in the title_

Comment: @Olaf: That's a narrow way to interpret things, and unhelpful to the question at hand.

Comment: @Gam yes, but its only for testing... but when I using line 1, its printed ok

Comment: You are not comparing your strings correctly. Use [std::strcmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp)

Comment: @Olaf yes true, but I want to separate some blocks of chars' from original char pointer

Comment: Also use `new char[]` not `malloc`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: If you try to understand it is actually very helpful. But agreed, that might involve knowing some basics.

Comment: @DevonRavihansa: Once more: A pointer has no char's! If that is not clear, I'd recommend to ask your tutor what a pointer actually is and types in general. As you are on C++, use the string class; will save you a lot of thinking …

Comment: its a long process. as it is added to hashmap then i got the values through it. but i failed to load, so then just i tested as this.

Comment: @Galik yeah, i have tried using new char[], but not works

Comment: yeah true, string is easy. but i want an algorithm to do in c.as its for embedded development too

Comment: @DevonRavihansa The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I think in this case the key insight--that `==` compares addresses--might not be made apparent by a debugger.

Comment: @Dietrich Fair point.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks, as i'm a beginner to C development sorry for mistakes

Comment: @DevonRavihansa C and C++ aren't the same languages, just FYI.

Comment: sure, but what are the differences that i missed here

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of different ways you can do this.

### Printing a Substring

If you just want to print a substring of a `char *` to `cout`, use `write()`.

```
const char *str = alphabet;
int start_index = 2, end_index = 6;
std::cout.write(str + start_index, end_index - start_index);
```

### Constructing a std::string

If you want to construct a `std::string`:

```
const char *str = alphabet;
int start_index = 2, end_index = 6;
std::string substr{str + start_index, end_index - start_index};
std::string substr{str + start_index, str + end_index}; // equivalent
std::cout << substr;
const char *substr_ptr = substr.c_str(); // watch out for lifetime
```

### Comparing

If you want to compare, `if (p == "phab")` compares if `p` contains the same *address* as the address of `"phab"`.  The answer is "no", because `p` was created by `malloc()`.  You can compare `char *` strings using `std::strcmp()`.

```
if (std::strcmp(p, "phab") == 0) {
    cout << "ok\n";
}
```

Otherwise, the `substring()` function works fine, although it's not idiomatic C++ and doesn't do any error checking.  Remember that `std::malloc` can return NULL.  There's a reason why most people don't use `malloc` in C++.

Comment: thanks for you support too

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is trying to compare strings with `p == "phab"`.

That doesn't compare the strings, it compares their location in memory. To compare the strings use [std::strcmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp).

I made some annotations/suggestions to your code.

```
char* substring(const char* src, int start_index, int end_index) {

    int length = end_index - start_index;

    if (length < 0)
        return NULL;

    char* dest = new char[length + 1]; // use new[] not malloc

    std::copy(src + start_index, src + end_index, dest); // prefer to memcopy
    dest[length] = '\0';

    return dest;
}

int main() {
  //char *p = "phab"; // line 1
  char* p = substring("alphabet", 2, 6); // line 2

  cout << p << endl;

  // use strcmp()
  if (std::strcmp(p, "phab") == 0) cout << "ok\n";

  delete[] p; // don't forget to delete your memory
}
```

Comment: thanks for your support